# get json field from string identifier

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose I have a json that looks like this:

```
let jsonExample = {
    "name": "foo",
    "age": 43,
    "number" : 13,
    "id": "osaid9r"
}
```

My goal is to create a javascript function `getField(json, fieldName)` that receives a json and a string representing the field name and returns the value represented by `fieldName`.

```
getField(jsonExample, "name") = "foo"
getField(jsonExample, "number") = 13
```

How can I write such function?

Comment: `jsonExample["name"]` will return "foo", and you can substitute any string in for `"name"`, including a string variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write as this:

```js
let jsonExample = {
    "name": "foo",
    "age": 43,
    "number" : 13,
    "id": "osaid9r"
}
function getField(obj, field){ return obj[field];}
console.log(getField(jsonExample,"name"));
console.log(getField(jsonExample,"number"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let jsonExample = {"name": "foo","age": 43,"number" : 13,"id": "osaid9r"}

function getField(json, key)
{ 
    return json[key];
}


console.log(getField(jsonExample,"number"));
```